# how to save a model object in another model save method

Tags: django, django-models

I have user model that has a one to one relation with two other models.
these are my models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    isPreRegistered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=13)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, default=None)
    progress_level = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, choices=USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS)

class ScientificInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    final_assessment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_interviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class PsychologicInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    final_assessment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_interviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to update the user's progress_level if PsychologicInfo.is_interviewed and ScientificInfo.is_interviewed are both True. So I thought I should override the save method and added this to the user model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.scientificinfo.is_interviewed == True and self.psychologicinfo.is_interviewed == True:
        self.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[1][0]
    return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I have to save the User object one more time to see some results. how can I update my progress level field when PsychologicInfo and ScientificInfo get saved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Django signals a post_save can be what you need.
U can make a check if the instance **PsychologicInfo** or **ScientificInfo**
are updated or created then update the progress

voila an example of what you may want:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import PsychologicInfo, ScientificInfo

# import your choices USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS     

@receiver(post_save, sender=PsychologicInfo)
def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
if instance: 
   if instance.psychologicinfo.is_interviewed:
      instance.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[1][0]
      # Do other operation ...
```

You duplicate the this code by changing the **sender** and change the logique of your condition. it should work just fine